# ant reusing fileset in multiple targets

Tags: php, ant

i am trying to reuse ant fileset in multiple targets. but cant get it to work:

```
<project name="calltivation" default="build">


    <fileset id="components" dir="${basedir}/components/com_calltivation">
        <include name="**/*.php"/>
        <!-- Exclude the unittest folder here  -->
        <exclude name="**/unittest/**"/>
        <modified/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset id="modules" dir="${basedir}/modules">
        <include name="**/*calltivation*/*.php"/>
        <modified/>
    </fileset>

    <fileset id="plugins" dir="${basedir}/plugins">
        <include name="**/*calltivation*/*.php"/>
        <modified/>
    </fileset>

   ....
   .......
   <target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
        <apply executable="php" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-l"/>

            <path rfid="components"/>
            <path rfid="modules"/>
            <path rfid="components"/>

        </apply>
    </target>

</project>
```

When i try to run it:

path doesn't support the "rfid" attribute

What is the proper way to reference the fileset inside the target ? any idea?

Comment: its refid NOT rfid..ugh!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who faces this silly issue:

wrap the filesets in path element:

```
 <path id="sources">
        <fileset id="components" dir="${basedir}/components/com_calltivation">
            <include name="**/*.php"/>
            <!-- Exclude the unittest folder here  -->
            <exclude name="**/unittest/**"/>
            <modified/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset id="modules" dir="${basedir}/modules">
            <include name="**/*calltivation*/*.php"/>
            <modified/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset id="plugins" dir="${basedir}/plugins">
            <include name="**/*calltivation*/*.php"/>
            <modified/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
```

And then use the refid:

```
<target name="lint" description="Perform syntax check of sourcecode files">
        <apply executable="php" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-l"/>

            <path refid="sources"/>


        </apply>
    </target>
```

Hope it helps someone.Or atleast me in future

Comment: The filset task also accepts a refid parameter: <fileset refid="myFileSet"/>